# Pivoting the column values and flagging using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table with unique Id and the respective values:

```
C1   C2
1    A;B
2    A
3    C;D;A
4    D;C;E
5    E
```

I want to transform in a way like below:

```
C1  A  B  C  D  E
1   1  1  0  0  0 
2   1  0  0  0  0
3   1  0  1  1  0
4   0  0  1  1  1
5   0  0  0  0  1
```

I have came across like this somewhere, but am not getting any clue how to do this.

Comment: Search for mysql explode csv. MYSQL does not have any built in functionality to do this. Then search for mysql pivot. IF you have some other technology in play consider using that if it has arrays (which sql does not)

Comment: Are A, B, C, D, E the only values?

Comment: @forpas, yes only those !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LIKE operator for each column:

```
select C1,
  concat(';', c2, ';') like '%;A;%'  A,
  concat(';', c2, ';') like '%;B;%'  B,
  concat(';', c2, ';') like '%;C;%'  C,
  concat(';', c2, ';') like '%;D;%'  D,
  concat(';', c2, ';') like '%;E;%'  E
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/drBkWKj2wFGvMu62BYLzJW/0).
If A, B, C, D, E are the actual values in your table you can simplify to this:

```
select C1,
  c2 like '%A%'  A,
  c2 like '%B%'  B,
  c2 like '%C%'  C,
  c2 like '%D%'  D,
  c2 like '%E%'  E
from tablename
```

Results:

```
| C1  | A   | B   | C   | D   | E   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 1   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 2   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 3   | 1   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 0   |
| 4   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
| 5   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   |
```

Comment: What if there are any values other than A,B,C,D,E ?

Comment: You will have to add similar code like the code for A, B, C, D, E.

Comment: No, but it will not show in the results the other columns. But try it.

Comment: Okay I will try that !